# What is "Kamisama ni Natta Hi" episode 12 ending theme?

Tags: theme-song, the-day-i-became-a-god

What is *Kamisama ni Natta Hi* episode 12 ending theme?

I tried finding it but I suck at finding things. What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ending theme of *Kamisama ni Natta Hi* episode 12 is *Takaramono ni Natta Hi* by Jun Maeda x Nagi Yanagi, which is also an insert song in episode 5.

[image]

<sup>Insert songs listed in episode 12 ending, featuring *Natsu Nagi* and *Takaramono ni Natta Hi*</sup>